# QLabel: set color of text and background

Tags: qt, qt4, qlabel

How do I set color of text and background of a `QLabel` ?

Answer (score 328, accepted):

The best and recommended way is to use Qt Style Sheet. Docs: [Qt 5 Style Sheet](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html), [Qt 6 Style Sheet](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/stylesheet.html).

To change the text color and background color of a `QLabel`, here is what I would do :

```
QLabel* pLabel = new QLabel;
pLabel->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : red; color : blue; }");
```

You could also avoid using Qt Style Sheets and change the `QPalette` colors of your `QLabel`, but you might get different results on different platforms and/or styles.

As Qt documentation states :

> Using a QPalette isn't guaranteed to work for all styles, because style authors are restricted by the different platforms' guidelines and by the native theme engine.

But you could do something like this :

```
 QPalette palette = ui->pLabel->palette();
 palette.setColor(ui->pLabel->backgroundRole(), Qt::yellow);
 palette.setColor(ui->pLabel->foregroundRole(), Qt::yellow);
 ui->pLabel->setPalette(palette);
```

But as I said, I strongly suggest not to use the palette and go for Qt Style Sheet.

Comment: The `color` attribute is ineffective.  Only via HTML `<font color="#FFFFFF">...</font>` I was able to set font color (to white in this case.

Answer (score 62):

You can use QPalette, however you must set `setAutoFillBackground(true);` to enable background color

```
QPalette sample_palette;
sample_palette.setColor(QPalette::Window, Qt::white);
sample_palette.setColor(QPalette::WindowText, Qt::blue);

sample_label->setAutoFillBackground(true);
sample_label->setPalette(sample_palette);
sample_label->setText("What ever text");
```

It works fine on Windows and Ubuntu, I haven't played with any other OS.

Note: Please see [QPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html), color role section for more details

Comment: This is the most important single element of ANY approach (except styleSheets.)

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that the autoFillBackground is a key issue here. The accepted answer above does not work without that setting.

Answer (score 28):

I add this answer because I think it could be useful to anybody.

I step into the problem of setting [RGBA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGBA_color_space) colors (that is, RGB color with an Alpha value for transparency) for color display labels in  my painting application.

As I came across the first answer, I was unable to set an RGBA color. I have also tried things like:

`myLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color : %s"%color.name())`

where `color` is an RGBA color.

So, my dirty solution was to extend `QLabel` and override `paintEvent()` method filling its bounding rect.

Today, I've open up the `qt-assistant` and read the [style reference properties list](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties). Affortunately, it has an example that states the following:

`QLineEdit { background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0) }`

Thats open up my mind in doing something like the code below, as an example:

```py
myLabel= QLabel()
myLabel.setAutoFillBackground(True) # This is important!!
color  = QtGui.QColor(233, 10, 150)
alpha  = 140
values = "{r}, {g}, {b}, {a}".format(r = color.red(),
                                     g = color.green(),
                                     b = color.blue(),
                                     a = alpha
                                     )
myLabel.setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color: rgba("+values+"); }")
```

Note that `setAutoFillBackground()` set in `False` will not make it work.

Regards,

Answer (score 14):

The ONLY thing that worked for me was html.

And I found it to be the far easier to do than any of the programmatic approaches.

The following code changes the text color based on a parameter passed by a caller.

```
enum {msg_info, msg_notify, msg_alert};
:
:
void bits::sendMessage(QString& line, int level)
{
    QTextCursor cursor = ui->messages->textCursor();
    QString alertHtml  = "<font color=\"DeepPink\">";
    QString notifyHtml = "<font color=\"Lime\">";
    QString infoHtml   = "<font color=\"Aqua\">";
    QString endHtml    = "</font><br>";

    switch(level)
    {
        case msg_alert:  line = alertHtml % line; break;
        case msg_notify: line = notifyHtml % line; break;
        case msg_info:   line = infoHtml % line; break;
        default:         line = infoHtml % line; break;
    }

    line = line % endHtml;
    ui->messages->insertHtml(line);
    cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor::End);
    ui->messages->setTextCursor(cursor);
}
```

Answer (score 13):

The best way to set any feature regarding the colors of any widget is to use [QPalette](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qpalette.html).

And the easiest way to find what you are looking for is to open Qt Designer and set the palette of a QLabel and check the generated code.

Comment: In designer, click "Form->View Code" to see the generated code.

Answer (score 7):

#### This one is working perfect

```
QColorDialog *dialog = new QColorDialog(this);
QColor color=  dialog->getColor();
QVariant variant= color;
QString colcode = variant.toString();
ui->label->setStyleSheet("QLabel { background-color :"+colcode+" ; color : blue; }");
```

`getColor()` method returns the selected color.
You can change label  color using `stylesheet`

Comment: While this code works, there are some definate optimizations

<code>
    QColor color = QColorDialog::getColor( QColor( Qt::white ), this, tr( "Select Color" ); // use the static function to select the color, the initial value is white </br>
    ui->label->setStyleSheet( QString( "QLabel { background-color :%1; color : blue; }""+colcode+" ; color : blue; }" ).arg( color.name() ); // color.name returns a #RRGGBB formatted string
</code>