# Setting alpha to zero does not make my label transparent

Tags: qt

I have a label in my main window that displays some text. I also have a background image in the main window that needs to show through the label. Only the background and the text should be visible.

I've set the alpha to zero with a white label background following the instructions I found on SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948453/c-over-qt-controlling-transparency-of-labels-and-buttons) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2749798/qlabel-set-color-of-text-and-background)).

```
label->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);");
```

However, I still see a dark box.

Answer (score 0):

You should set your main window transparent by adding these to the constructor of your main window :

```
setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
```

You can also create a borderless dialog by setting `Qt::FramelessWindowHint` window flag :

```
setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
```