# It is possible to set the CSS white-space of a QtQuick Label to pre-wrap?

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols

I have a QtQuick `Label` in a QML file like so:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3 as Controls
Controls.Label {
    id: lbl
    text: "This is        some <b>bold text</b> with extra      white space"
}
```

If the `text` property of my label contains any HTML, then the label renders it as HTML and the multiple spaces in the original text are compressed down to a single space (if the text contains no HTML then it is rendered as normal text and the spaces are preserved).

`QWidget` has a `setStyleSheet` method that apparently supports the style "white-space: pre-wrap" which is what I need to get the HTML rendering to preserve the whitespace, but I'm not sure if I can apply this to a Label in a QML file. Is there any way to achieve this?

**Edit:** This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2756376/14606 shows setting the styleSheet property for a `QLabel`. Is there any way to write a function that will let me pass my QtQuick `Label` and cast it as a `QLabel` and set the stylesheet in this way?

Comment: A Label is not a QWidget, nor does it inherit, nor can you cast QLabel so forget it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually achieve what I was looking for (a `Label` that can display HTML while preserving white space) by doing a text replace on your original string and replacing all regular spaces (" ") with `&#8203;&#32;` (which is a zero-length string followed by a regular string). The `Label` will then faithfully render consecutive spaces, as if the white-space style had been set to pre-wrap. Unfortunately this only kind of works (for my purposes at least) since the `Label` does not handle line wrapping the same way in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know is how to apply css in qml, instead of code (`widget.setStyleSheet("...")`) ?

Have you tried this?

```
Controls.Label {
    id: lbl;
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    text: "This is        some <b>bold text</b> with extra      white space";
}
```

edit: Since white-space is not a property of Label, you need to set this property for the label text.

If possible (just guessing) use:

```
Controls.Label.Text {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
```

But if not, use this workaround:

```
Controls.Label {
    id: lbl;
    textFormat: Text.RichText;
    text: "<style>white-space: pre-wrap;</style>This is        some <b>bold text</b> with extra      white space";
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, white-space is not a property of a Label.

Comment: Label only supports this HTML subset: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html which doesn't include the style tag - so "white-space; pre-wrap;" shows up in the displayed text.

Comment: are you 100% sure you have `textFormat: Text.RichText;` set? I think `<style>` is not a property itself, it defines css properties. it's just html afaik.

Comment: It's actually set to `Text.AutoText` so it shows Text.RichText as necessary (like if there's HTML tags there). It does not render the <style> and </style> tags themselves, but it ignores the tags and does render the text in between them ("white-space: pre-wrap;") as if it were any other ordinary text.